# Setting Netbean's defaults

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, compilation, settings

Two-part question:

1. It is needed for ALL my projects to start with certain "layout", for example `#include <math.h>` etc.
2. Compiling - I know I can set compiling options for each project individually but I haven't found a way to set options globally. It is annoying to have to set up options for each project individually. Basically, what is needed is for every project to have `-Wall -pedantic -lm` etc.

I repeat, not for each individual project, globally or as default. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> It is needed for ALL my projects to start with certain "layout", for example #include  etc.

Go to Tools -> Templates

Select and choose Open In Editor `C Source File` , and/or `C Main File`, and/or `C++ Source File` and/or `C++ Main File` and put

```
#include <math.h>
```

in the file and save the template.

After this every time you create a new source file of the appropriate type it will have the #include  at the top.

> Compiling - I know I can set compiling options for each project individually but I haven't found a way to set options globally. It is annoying to have to set up options for each project individually. Basically, what is needed is for every project to have -Wall -pedantic -lm etc.

The best way to do this is to create a project without adding anything, set the settings you want. Every time you need to create a new project. Select this project with the settings already set and right click on it and choose `Copy ...` to copy this to a new directory and project name with settings already set.